# Problem with PID - Zabbix Server on Ubuntu (WSL2)

Tags: zabbix

I'm having trouble trying to start Zabbix Server (6.4) on WSL2. When I try the following command:

`service zabbix-server restart`:

I received the following message:

```
 * Stopping Zabbix server zabbix_server
No process in pidfile '/var/run/zabbix/zabbix_server.pid' found running; none killed.   [ OK ]
 * Starting Zabbix server zabbix_server
```

And Zabbix Server does not start:

`service zabbix-server status`:

```
 * zabbix_server is not running
```

Inside the log file (/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server.log), is found the follow message repeated several times:

```
13660:20230417:160028.155 [Z3001] connection to database 'zabbix' failed: [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)
```

Followed with the message in the end of the file:

```
13660:20230417:160028.155 database is down: reconnecting in 10 seconds 13660:20230417:160032.344 Got signal [signal:15(SIGTERM),sender_pid:15318,sender_uid:0,reason:0]. Exiting ... 
13660:20230417:160032.344 Zabbix Server stopped. Zabbix 6.4.1 (revision 546e284fd7c).
```

But I already installed the mysql-server normally, and it is running without any kind of problem.

Comment: Are there any error messages in a log file? Maybe in `/var/log/zabbix/`?

Comment: in the log I have this messages repeated several times:

 13660:20230417:160028.155 [Z3001] connection to database 'zabbix' failed: [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)
 13660:20230417:160028.155 database is down: reconnecting in 10 seconds

 13660:20230417:160032.344 Got signal [signal:15(SIGTERM),sender_pid:15318,sender_uid:0,reason:0]. Exiting ...

13660:20230417:160032.344 Zabbix Server stopped. Zabbix 6.4.1 (revision 546e284fd7c).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the contents of the log file, and add the name of the file if there is more than one. Did you install and start a MySQL (or maybe MariaDB) server?

Comment: yes, and it is starting without any problem.

Comment: Check the `mysql` log files as well.